How to set keep above state on a Gtk4 window to keep on top?
I am trying to keep gtk4 window on top but gtk_window_set_keep_above function is Removed from gtk4. Is there any other way to set window state on top?

On what system?  Generally there will be a problem if more than one window asks to be always on top. Who will win?

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gtk4-set-window-always-on-top-and-on-center-of-current-monitor/9068 might be of interest.

There is no replacement in GTK4 for
gtk_window_set_keep_above

This is probably due to the fact that GTK4 can be used with different window managers, all of which act differently.
You can only try the on-board tools of your system if you want a GTK window to stay at the top.
Greetings
